# Can we get rid of this old locked question on semicolons in JavaScript?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, historical-lock

There's an old and now locked question about semicolons in JavaScript:
*[Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)*.

Not only is this question inappropriate for Stack Overflow, it is subjective and it is also a poll. Even worse, there are subjective answers with a high amount of votes and an "accepted" mark. This may (and very well will) lead many visitors, especially new ones, to accept those answers as some sort of truth.

Unfortunately I cannot vote for its closure because it is somehow locked. Can somebody with enough rights please delete it?

Just to sum it up, what new users see when they enter this page: "Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?" - "74 + checkmark at the top: **Yes, you should use semicolons after every statement in JavaScript.**" Not only is this off-topic, it is FUD and Stack Overflow makes it look very much like some kind of accepted truth.

Comment: Why? The Lock message says it all, doesn't it? That's exactly why it has been locked. Valuable information (possibly), so preserved. But don't ask it again.

Comment: I don't see the problem, but can a **moderator** please remove the *"This answer and its opposite are intended as a poll. Vote for the one you agree with, and then post an answer with your reasons if you like.*" from the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/444084) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/444082). That just looks tacky, especially since you can't vote on them anymore. They could also clean up the link-only answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6651902) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4996556).

Comment: @animuson I cleaned up the wording in the posts, but I'm keeping the link-only answers. They link to relevant information and, let's face it, given the choice between "Yes, you should"/"No, you shouldn't" answers and the answers with links here, the latter win on quality and usefulness.

Comment: Because "it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site" only talks about question and only touches that it is "not on-topic". It doesn't say anything about it being stupid question, nor does it say anything about answers. And yes, I've seen links to this question and answer in the wild.

Comment: Semicolons, man. Those gosh darned semicolons. The bane of our existence as programmers.

Comment: Just to sum it up, what new users sees when he enters this page: "Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?" - "74 + checkmark at the top: Yes, you should use semicolons after every statement in JavaScript." Not only this is offtopic, this is FUD.

Comment: I'm with Oleg, unlock and let the community decide if it's really that valuable. I don't think it is. This same debate will happen again and again all around the world, and there's always going to be a certain percentage of the population that refuses to agree on a coding standard. In short, there's no actual resolution to a problem here except to give people more talking points for the debate. +1

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - Well, I do think it is a good idea to use semicolons. It makes the code more readable, especially considering JavaScript uses a C-style syntax like C, C++, and Java, and these are often the first languages most people are exposed to in university. So why be different and confuse the hell out of people. Not everyone has read the JavaScript spec. Whether or not everyone should read it is a different debate altogether, but people tend to do better when things are similar and what they normally expect to see.

Comment: I guess I agree with it's removal, but not because it's wrong... because it's not a constructive question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jmort253, I'm perfectly fine with **you** thinking that and actually consider the only rule to for coding style to be: "whatever everyone else is using in your project". I'm not fine with subjective answer promoted as universal truth though.

Comment: When something is a universal truth, when there's a standard, it means any programmer from anywhere in the world can drop in on your project and quickly assimilate into a development role. If everyone just does their own thing because it's cool, then that advantage no longer stands. I don't have data on this, and I'm not going to claim that I know the answer to this, but it would be interesting to see the percentage of JavaScript developers who use semicolons vs those who don't. One thing's for sure, when you see documentation/examples on sites like Google, there are semicolons......

Comment: Alright you guys let's end all our sentences with semicolons;

Comment: I'm not opposed to unlocking or removing the question if there's community support for doing that... but so far the votes on this question suggest otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, that first answer, that's a f'n keeper.

Comment: @AnnaLear Wait till Monday, I guarantee the votes will go the other way.

Comment: @casperOne And I'll be happy to take action when they do. :)

Comment: -1, just because the accepted answer violates your religious preferences doesn't mean the entire question should be deleted.  The answers in the middle of the question are very good and shine enough additional light onto the semicolon issue to make it a decent enough resource.

Comment: @AnnaLear It's difficult to evaluate community support by the score of the question, because there are downvotes to say “leave it locked” and downvotes to say “unlock it if you like but don't delete it”. Objectively, the accepted answer is worthless and needs deleting, whatever else happens. Stack Exchange is not just a popularity contest, useful content is a goal.

Comment: @Gilles For the most part downvotes on this question seem to point towards "don't take action", which is fine enough. Your answer now provides a clearer action to vote on, so let's see how that goes.

Comment: @Charles, you've missed that entire question violates current policy, right? Not to mention that answer itself happens to be just another "religious preference".

Answer (score 10):

Accepted answer:

> Yes, you should use semicolons after every statement in JavaScript.

Because… No, the answer doesn't say. Nor do the comments against the answer. This is not an answer, it's a useless bit of screen estate. This answer needs to be deleted.

There are other answers that contribute reasoning and that might salvage the thread. Not all of them, there are several other answers that need deleting, but there's enough worthwhile content that could be edited into shape. For this to happen, **the thread needs to be unlocked**. As a close contender, delete this question and let it be reasked and answered in a more constructive way.

This is a showcase example of why [historical locks are bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112910/do-not-lock-old-questions).

Comment: If it was a short hop to making this good content, I'd be more than content to unlock it (because it means that we can make it good for the site, dammit), but this thing is a crap shoot out of the gate, which means I agree with your runner up suggestion, delete it and see if someone can reask it in a way that's suitable for the site now.

Comment: @casperOne, any news on this "impossible to be moderated by community" question? Year passed and it is still there.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Well, since you noticed it, deleting it stealthily in the middle of the night isn't going to happen.  THANKS FOR RUNING IT!

Comment: @casperOne, well unlocking it and letting it go usual way would be more than enough.

Comment: What's wrong with unlocking and making it go poof immediately afterwards? Unlocking without making it go away doesn't decrease the mess but relies on others to clean it up afterward. Polishing a turd. Just delete the turd and see if anyone else feels the need to ask it again. If it's not in a constructive manner, delete it again. If it *is* in a constructive manner, we finally got somewhere.

Comment: @Mast That's my point. I want it unlocked to be able to delete it.